# .env file is not providing process.env.XYZ newly added env variable in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my past project -
I added a new env variable like XYZ. When I'm trying to get process.env.XYZ then it's giving undefined.
But others env variables are working when i access.

> .env

```
ABC = "https ://abc.com/api" // old, working
XYZ= "https ://xyz.com/api"  // new, not working
```

> my next.config.js is -

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const nextEnv = require('next-env');
const dotenvLoad = require('dotenv-load');
const sass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const progressBar = require('next-progressbar');
const graphql = require('next-plugin-graphql');
const images = require('next-images');

dotenvLoad();
const env = nextEnv();
const distDir = '.next';

const nextConfig = { distDir };

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [[sass], [env], [progressBar], [graphql], [images]],
  nextConfig
);
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: yeah, @Stephen ... It's works on ssr, but not in csr